# read a column from a excel sheet & display on textbox vba

Tags: vba, excel

Read all the rows for one column & display on textbox(s) which are created at run time.I am turning over to seek you assistance for below after several attempts which didn't help.

`Name`

`ABC`

`AB`

`ABCEF`

`GHFD`

I want all the rows from excel sheet to be shown in textbox just as they appear in sheet for a particular column.I am creating 4 textbox(s) that represent columns & 11 textbox(s) that represent rows. For the first column, I want the data to be displayed as it is in sheet. I am successful in creating text box as per my requirement but not able to display data as per needs. Thanks a ton for help

`Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()`

```
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Testing")

sh.Range("F21").Activate

With sh
    fatalcount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F:F"), "Fatal")
    Majorcount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F:F"), "Major")
    Minorcount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F:F"), "Minor")
End With

For jrow = 1 To 11
For i = 0 To 4
    Set txtB1 = WtmsFrm.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    With txtB1
    .Name = "chkDemo" & i
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 5 + 50 + 5
    .Left = 10 + 50 * i + 2
    .Top = 15 * jrow + 10
    .ControlTipText = "Type of Bug"
    End With
 Next i
Next jrow

For Each tbox In  Frm.Controls
   ' For counter = 2 To 11

    If tbox.Name = "chkDemo" Then

        tbox.Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(counter, 2).Value  ' failing code
        tbox.ControlTipText = "Name"

    ElseIf tbox.Name = "chkDemo1" Then
        tbox.Value = 1

    ElseIf tbox.Name = "chkDemo2" Then
        tbox.Value = 2
    ElseIf tbox.Name = "chkDemo3" Then
        tbox.Value = 3
     ElseIf tbox.Name = "chkDemo4" Then
        tbox.Value = 4
    End If
   ' Next counter

Next


' Initialise the followings
 Frm.txtFatal.Value = fatalcount

 Frm.txtMajor.Value = Majorcount

 Frm.txtMinor.Value = Minorcount

 Frm.txtTotoal.Value = fatalcount + Majorcount + Minorcount

End Sub
```

Comment: You want dynamic textbox to appear at side by side?

Comment: @Karthick  yes, Here the columns are fixed & rows can change. In addition, I want the first column  to display data from excel.

Comment: use textbox position to appear where ever you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you create a textbox named `"chkDemo"`. They all have a number appended. As you take `tbox` from all controls, there might be a control on your sheet somewhere named `"chkDemo"` but which is not a textbox. Neither do I see `counter` declared or initialized. That might also let the code fail.

Note also that with `.Name = "chkDemo" & i` you give the same name to textboxes because you are also in a `For jrow` loop.